# Acrobat reader equivalent of MS powerpoint Slide sorter view

Tags: adobe-reader

How to view all pages of a PDF document in somekind of outline mode.

I tried to get it going by --Clicking on Pages Menu(which is present on left side ) in Acrobat reader. Then enlarge that view by pulling its boundaries wide. Then Right click enlarge page thumbnails until , i could see some text visible, but this could not really give me a unified view of the pdf pages such that text in each is visible.

Is there any way in any Acrobat reader (any version) to see all the pages present in the document in one single page, like a 'Slide sorter' view in MS powerpoint.

Answer (score 2):

If you repeat the "Enlarge thumbnails" operation in Acrobat viewer, you can eventually make the thumbnails large enough to read text.

Another option is to view two-up and zoom out but this only ever gives you two pages per row.

Comment: Enlarge thumnails worked well. I wish there was a built in command to quickly do this (enlarge thumnails, increase area for thumbnails, and then all back to original).